# HttpResponseException thrown during InsertAsync at .NET Backend Mobile service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Firstly, I had this problem where the value of RequestStatus is unable to passed from client to Mobile Service during InsertAsync, which will be processed in null
(client - mobile app)
[image]
(server - Azure .NET Backend Mobile Service)
[image]
Secondly, I had also tried to change its value in the debugger in order to process, but HttpResponseException is still thrown. Detailed error message are as follow:

```
{"Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details."}

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.TableController`1.<InsertAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at EasyPark.MobileService.Controllers.RequestController.<PostRequest>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\EasyPark\EasyPark.MobileService\Controllers\RequestController.cs:line 45
```

As an extra, here is what i caught in Fiddler

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed just by removing the [DefaultValue("Available")] Annotation in Azure Mobile Service.